# Which collection type to use for JOIN linq in .NET Core EF?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using .NET Core with EF and I've got to perform join operation on 2 tables from different databases, so I can't use just `IQueryable`.

I'm wondering which collection type will be the best when it's obligatory to upload all the values from DB to local memory and the amount of data of the both tables is quite big, and later we want to LINQ join both tables?

I don't want to update/delete any values later.

In my opinion, the best would be a `HashSet` or maybe even better `Dictionary`?

But what's your opinion and why? Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to do preemptive optimization. `Join` itself uses effective lookup techniques.